# Is there a way to program a wallpaper for windows?

Tags: desktop-wallpaper

My buddy wants me to program a wallpaper for his birthday. The idea he has would require some code to be run in order for his idea to work. I would need access to get a timestamp and draw to the background.

I believe he is running windows 10, but he could be running windows 8. Is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Wallpaper or screensaver?

Comment: Wallpaper, Background, etc.

Comment: I know it's late but you can look here for c#: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/856020/draw-behind-desktop-icons-in-windows-plus
and here for c++: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56132584/draw-on-windows-10-wallpaper-in-c